# Solve the equation $x^4-8x^3+23x^2-30x+15=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quartics

Solve the equation $$x^4-8x^3+23x^2-30x+15=0$$
As $x=0$ is obviously not a solution, we can consider $x\ne0$, so I have tried to divide both sides by $x^2$ to get $$x^2-8x+23-\dfrac{30}{x}+\dfrac{15}{x^2}=0$$ Clearly this does not help. I have also tried to find the rational roots using Horner's method. It seems that the polynomial in the left-hand side does not have rational roots.

Comment: It factors as the product of two quadratics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that, if $p(x)$ is your polynomial, then $p(x+2)=x^4-x^2-2x-1=x^4-(x+1)^2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! Not at all. I don't know where $p(x+2)$ came from and how it is equal to the expression you wrote.

Comment: Are you telling me that, given that $p(x)=x^4-8x^3+23x^2-30x+15$, you have no clue about how to compute $p(x+2)$?

Comment: I guess I should simplify $P(x+2)=(x+2)^4-8(x+2)^3+23(x+2)^2-30(x+2)+15$ but I don't see the point of that and it won't be clear.

Comment: @mat1 He said that let $y = x - 2$ and then you'll have $y^4 - y^2 - 2y - 1 = 0$. Find the roots of the simpler equation and substitute them to find $x$.

Comment: Since $p(x+2)=x^4-(x+1)^2$,\begin{align}p(x+2)=0&\iff x^4=(x+1)^2\\&\iff x^2=x+1\text{ or }x^2=-x-1.\end{align}And now all you have to do is to solve two quadratics.

Comment: How do we get $p(x+2)=0$? And why are we taking exactly $p(x+2)$? Why not e.g. $p(x-3)$ or $p(x+200)$?

Comment: It's a standard trick to deal with quartics: if $q(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then $q\left(x-\frac a4\right)$ is a polynomial with no cubic term. In your case, $a=-8$, and so I computed $p\left(x-\frac{-8}4\right)=p(x+2)$.

Comment: Thank you! And why are we taking $p(x+2)=0$? We want $p(x)=0$, right?

Comment: The solutions of the equation $p(x)=0$ are those numbers $x$ such that $p\bigl((x-2)+2\bigr)=0$. So, take the solutions of the equation $p(x+2)=0$ and subtract $2$ to each of them to get the solutions of the equation $p(x)=0$.

Comment: So $x=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$. If we subtract $2$, then we'll get $x=\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt5}{2}$. Shouldn't we add 2?

Comment: No. I made a mistake. We have to add $2$, not to subtract. So, the real solutions are $\frac{5\pm\sqrt 5}2$. There are also two complex non-real solutions.

Comment: I am really amazed by your solution and I am still trying to comprehend it. The one thing I don't understand is why we have to add $2$ to the solutions of the equation $p(x+2)=0$ to get the solutions of the equation $p(x)=0$. I don't understand this statement of yours at all: "The solutions of the equation $p(x)=0$ are those numbers x such that $p((x−2)+2)=0$."

Comment: Can you clarify for me why if $q(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then $q(x-\frac{a}{4})$ is a polynomial with no cubic term? Can we use this trick to deal with quartics if the leading coefficient isn't equal to $1$, or if the coefficient of $x^3$ isn't a divisor of $4$? For example, the equation $x^4 - 10x^3 + 21x^2 + 40x - 100 = 0$. If $c(x)$ is the polynomial in this case, then we will have $c(x+\frac{5}{2})=x^4-\dfrac{33}{2}x^2+20x+\dfrac{225}{16}$ which isn't "nice".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132659/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-mat1).

Answer (score 4):

Since you tried the rational root theorem and didn't find any rational roots, then next thing to try is factoring as a product of two quadratics.  Set your polynomial equal to

$$(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$ $$=x^4 + (a+c)x^3+(d+ac+b)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd$$

and equate coefficients.  Since $bd=15$ you can try $b=3$, $d=5$ and see what $a$ and $c$ turn out to be.  If that doesn't work, try $b=1$, $d=15$.